# Filter across dashboard components

Tags: tableau

Is it possible to create a dashboard filter that will filter the data across all the components in the dashboard.  For example, if all the components have quarterly data and have a quarter field, can I add a filter at the top of the dashboard that I can change and it will update the data showing in all the components.  I can successfully add a filter to one component.  I am not sure I am using the correct terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a common filter for multiple worksheets. On dashboard just show the filter from any of contained worksheets, and that will work for all of them.
[image]